# Are htaccess questions ever on-topic at SO?

Tags: discussion, faq, scope, site-recommendation

Can writing `.htaccess` files for Web servers be on-topic for Stack Overflow?

- It can be argued that these are simply configuration files for standard network servers, and so a subject for Server Fault.
- Alternatively, you can argue that they're a domain-specific language that includes some programming features, such as regular expressions, and therefore suitable for Stack Overflow.

Which Stack Exchange site is appropriate for such questions?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache configuration/.htaccess questions (esp. mod_rewrite): SO or SF?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6235/apache-configuration-htaccess-questions-esp-mod-rewrite-so-or-sf)

Comment: Also see [mod_rewrite questions getting migrated to SF](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39063/mod-rewrite-questions-getting-migrated-to-sf) (given most ".htaccess" questions end up being mod_rewrite questions).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

They fit both.

I'm not browsing [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/tour) (SF) much, but I assume that they are a bit annoyed by the amount of dull .htaccess/RewriteRule questions we are moving over.

And factually .htaccess files do not constitute server configuration. They share the same format and obviously Apache evaluates those files. But semantically they are application configuration data (`php_flag short_open_tag` and `SetEnv LC_ALL it_IT`). There are very few server settings (`ThreadsPerChild` or `PidFile`) you can factually set via .htaccess. There are quite involving options like nested <Files> and LogFormats or complex authentication modules which certainly belong on SF. But the majority of RewriterRule+RewriteCond inquiries can actually be handled on Stack Overflow.

SF has one interesting page for that topic: [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-ask) - but it doesn't quite cover regular expressions. I think it might actually make sense to create a similar reference question on SO, but concentrating on regex syntax and practical examples - which isn't yet covered.

Comment: "I assume that [ServerFault] are a bit annoyed by the amount of dull .htaccess/RewriteRule questions" - `.htaccess`/`RewriteRule` questions asked on SF are often closed as duplicates of the [catch-all mod_rewrite "guide"](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever) (as linked to above), whether they are covered by that "quide" or not. Generally, if you don't have direct access to the server config (in which case you probably wouldn't / shouldn't be using `.htaccess` anyway) then it's likely considered off-topic on SF.

Comment: This answer contains **absolutely no justification for why these questions are on-topic for Stack Overflow**. It merely explains why they're off-topic for Server Fault (both because it's not server configuration and because Server Fault community grows weary by the amount of questions they get about it).

Answer (score 11):

I'd argue they're a better fit for webmasters.stackexchange.com ... seems others have had the same thought (see the Q&A [Why do we need webmasters.stackexchange when we have Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283045/why-do-we-need-webmasters-stackexchange-when-we-have-stack-overflow)).

Answer (score 10):

I would have said `.htaccess` was a programming language - not a Turing complete (AFAIK) but neither is SQL

Answer (score 8):

Many, but not all, [.htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.htaccess) questions are definitely on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Any question about how you get

```
example.com/users/view/toby/
```

to redirect to

```
example.com/index.php?action=view&userid=toby
```

although asked 1000 times before, is still on-topic.

Questions about how you set up your `.htaccess` file to prevent access from two particular IP addresses on a Thursday afternoon in February, but only when the user has previously visited on a Friday is probably better off on [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tour) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/tour).

[.htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.htaccess) is an important part of many programmer's web application and as such is a necessary part of their understanding.

Comment: NB: Any _on-topic_ question which has been asked already is a duplicate, and should still be closed.