# Edit rejected, on a closed topic

Tags: support, accepted-answer, closed-questions, rejected-edits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10060656

Two reasons:

1. This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

   Comment is too short for my answer, and I can't answer a closed question.
2. This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive.

   Yes, I'm selling Apache Web Server for just $2 per copy.

I'm trying to edit this because the answer is not accurate as time goes by, and this has a pretty high votes which means a higher impact to users.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Spread it across multiple comments? But in general, if an answer works for an old version, it doesn't absolutely need to be updated to include new versions as well, as long as it's clear what versions it works for.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Thanks, but there is actually no version number mentioned anywhere, so it might confuse some users

Comment: So suggest an edit to add just that. (And maybe the IP address fix, if you really must have valid example IPs.)

Comment: I don't think anyone thinks you're shilling for Apache, the key part is `or is deliberately destructive.`

Comment: Why is it even closed?  It seems like it'd be useful and on-topic.  If it *stays* closed it just falls further out of date and out of disrepair.

Comment: Even though I don't think they should be, I guess that falls under "still permissible": [Are htaccess questions ever on-topic at SO?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283033/are-htaccess-questions-ever-on-topic-at-so/)