# When and how do mature [faq-proposed] posts graduate to [faq]?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

In the last year or so, a number of new [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) posts have been written, and have followed the guidelines in that tag's wiki for inclusion in [faq](/questions/tagged/faq). Some of them have made it, but most have not (including two by me and perhaps 3-5 others I think should really qualify).

What are the specific qualifications or signs of maturity that ♦ moderators use to determine which posts to promote?

- Post score? It seems that a number of the [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) questions and answers have higher scores than even considerably older [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) posts. A few have Great Question/Answer badges, or are close to them. A Q&A without at least Good Answer and probably Good Question too is not a great candidate for site FAQ, but that still leaves most of them in the running.
- Age since posting, or since last major edit? Nearly all of them have gone months at a stretch without significant changes. Some [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) posts got the nod within hours of posting.
- Community involvement in editing? This one's tougher, but it seems like there are a number of [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) answers that have had significant additions or adjustments from other editors, and some [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) that have had nearly none.
- Community buy-in via linking and duplicating? Some in [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) have upwards of 20 linked questions (the highest having 46 at present), which compares very favorably with the half-dozen or so several in [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) have.
- Precise adherence to [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) guidelines? Most of the posts meet all of them. But… you guessed it, certain [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) posts aren't CW or don't link back to the index.

Barring something I didn't think of, this looks rather haphazard. Can we get a more consistent process so we don't have a bunch of posts lying around that are only *nearly* official FAQs? This shouldn't be terribly onerous. It would probably be sufficient to make a quick pass, once a month, through anything that's been modified in the last month to see if it's now up to par. (Where "par" is loosely defined as "basically meets the guidelines, nice uncontroversial score, some reasonable community buy-in".)

Occasionally, some posts might meet the basic qualifications but still be somewhat lacking in the subjective judgment of the moderators. Judgment calls are what we elect them for, but in that case it would be nice to have an explicit "try addressing XYZ so this can be in the FAQ" comment from the mod making the call. Limbo is to be avoided.

Comment: [When a post seems to have hit a mature state, it will have faq added by a moderator.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251225/4639281) Whatever "mature" means in this case...

Comment: @TinyGiant: Yeah, I was kind of tacitly assuming that. All my metrics are more or less geared toward maturity in some sense.

Comment: [I asked this over 3 years ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149350/179419). Robert Harvey answered slightly, then deleted it. [Pops asked a similar question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110180/179419) almost exactly a year earlier... **tl;dr** there isn't a process, it seems to be random.

Comment: @Ben *I asked this ...* Liar! Ben is not ben is uǝq backwards. Caught you ಠ_ಠ

Comment: I hope it won't dissapoint you @Bhargav to learn I've been told this before: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213154/stray-hat-on-the-loose#comment686274_213154, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180825/are-there-any-chat-rules-on-stack-overflow#comment548962_180827, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161174/how-can-i-see-how-many-edits-left-for-archaeologist-badge#comment755453_161175

Comment: @Ben It doesn't disappoint me but imo *ben is uǝq rotated 180° along the central line* sounds better.

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) is exempt from the post score rule, right?

Comment: @dorukayhan: If you mean "did I include a vote-locked post in my count of [tag:faq] posts", no, I didn't. (I'm pretty sure I *did* include http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283033/are-htaccess-questions-ever-on-topic-at-so, asked in 2011 and never locked, though. At +24 it compares quite unfavorably with http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question, asked only a year and a half ago and already at +138.) But it's not a "rule", obviously, just an observation of a counterintuitive result.

Answer (score 10):

On a per-site Meta, it's really up to the moderators to add the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag to questions they think are worthy of them, but since I've been in the process of cleaning these up (slowly over time) over on the main Meta, I've also been curating some criteria I look for when determining whether something is worthy of being a FAQ or not, so I'll share them here.

- **Number of answers**. You might not think it, but it's hugely important. Unless there's just plain too much information to fit into a single answer, a FAQ simply should not have more than one answer. If it has more than one answer, then it should be edited so that all the information is contained in a single answer in a way that portrays the information accurately without elements of discussion or opinion. If that cannot be done, then the topic either hasn't reached a stage where the community can provide a definitive answer, or it's too open-ended to really be a FAQ anyways.

  To expand on this further, users don't search for FAQs to read a discussion on a topic. If they wanted to see a discussion, they can look at a huge array of other questions surrounding that topic. Users go to a FAQ because they want a **definitive answer**. They're curious about something and want to know the hard facts. If we can't provide that in the question, then we shouldn't advertise it as such.

  These situations often pop up when a large discussion has taken place and the community has reached a consensus. The easiest thing to do is to just slap a [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag on that question and call it good. **NO.** A much better solution is to create a *new* question which outlines the policies the community decided should stand. Again, definitive information without discussion.

  Leaving a FAQ sit around with all the discussion still behind it leads users to become confused, as it makes it look like the community *hasn't* really decided what the policy is, and all that information in the question has simply become words on a page. They're left with the feeling of "so, *is* this policy or just someone's opinion?"
- **Number of views.** Well, part of the acronym of FAQ is the word "frequently" - which implies it comes up a lot. If the question is rarely ever collecting views and no one is looking at it, then it is not coming up often enough to warrant the additional attention that a FAQ tag provides. The FAQ index should be kept clean and only contain relevant topics users are actually trying to find - we should avoid cluttering it with links to topics no one cares about.

  A lot of duplicate closures pointing back to the FAQ itself is also a pretty strong indicator that users are looking for this information often.
- **Information display.** Perhaps the biggest reason we start questions as *proposed* FAQs is because the first draft usually isn't the best way to display information to the user. It's just that, a first draft. Most proposed FAQs require much additional curating to provide proper formatting, separate information into understandable sections, make everything crystal clear, and overall make the exact piece of information a user wants to find - easy to find. If the entire answer looks like a book with paragraph after paragraph and no discernible way to find more relevant pieces of information, then it's definitely not ready.

As far as adhering to the FAQ standards, that's easily fixable with a couple of edits, and isn't something to be considered past "oh that needs to be done if I make this a FAQ." All the other factors you mention aren't really good factors for determining FAQ worthiness.

These are far from definite criteria, and I've kind of put processing these on hold for now as other things have come up and I'm exploring other options regarding this whole mess of FAQs that's becoming way too large to organize properly.

Comment: Re: Views. Not sure why I didn't think of that, but that's a very good point. There's still some inconsistencies there, with some proposals having 3k+ views and some FAQs having <1k. Most of the good proposals have only 1 answer, and the ones I'm thinking of appear to be fairly well organized internally, which seems to mostly leave it down to subjectivity and the general overscale of the FAQ system.

Comment: @NathanTuggy It's more just no one is looking at them to add the tag. Moderators don't exactly patrol the [meta-tag:faq-proposed] tag looking for things that need to be upgraded. Unless they stumble across it through natural use and go "oh, this never got changed" it's unlikely it's going to get changed without bringing it up in a flag.

Comment: @animuson So should a user flag the post if they figure it meets all other criteria?

Comment: Like [this FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites), which contains several highly-voted yet contradictory answers. I remember (long time ago) linking someone to that and them coming back confused like, wait, there's an answer there that says it's okay.

Comment: @CodyGray That is an excellent example of what a FAQ should *not* look like. I'm going to keep a link to that.

Comment: @animuson Speaking of that question... Is there a way to at least mark Jeff's answer as accepted, considering that he's Jeff and all?

Comment: @reirab That's fixed now. ;)

Comment: @TinyGiant Yes, similar to the process for getting any of the other moderator-only tags applied to a question.

Comment: @animuson: Can you add that as a summary/next steps to the answer?

Comment: That is good to know, here I was thinking that there was some kind of review process for these things.