# Add Voting to 'Closed as Off Topic' (at least after a time period elapses)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, scope

Can a vote up down 'button' be added to the "Marked as Closed" rulings that >3k folks may place on what might be considered by many to be relevant Question threads?

Comment: I see no admin involvement in the closure of that question.

Comment: Anyone with between 15 and 3000 rep can flag for closure, sending it to the close review queue.

Comment: I'd suggest your first step is to not insult the people with the power to close the questions, but that's me.

Comment: I love how your example of people closing more questions these days than they used to is a question that was closed *3 years ago*.

Comment: @leerssej A question being closed isn't throwing out the work.  Deleting the question would be throwing out the work.

Comment: @leerssej like the reopen vote and queue?

Comment: @leerssej:  That's already possible when you hit 3K+ reputation (as answered [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/336156/1079354)).

Comment: you get 3k rep and cast a vote, just like you would a close vote.

Comment: @leerssej Thanks for demonstrating that you haven't so much as even read the close banner under a closed question (let alone the help center) given that they specifically described *how to get the question reopened*.

Comment: The explanation is right in the help center: http://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions.  Among other things: "Closed questions that receive edits within the first 5 days of closure are automatically put into a review queue to be considered for reopening."

Comment: See also: [How often are closed questions reopened?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266709/how-often-are-closed-questions-re-opened)

Comment: @leerssej Indeed, you don't have 3k reputation, and as such cannot vote to reopen questions.  Given that you don't seem to understand what is and is not appropriate to ask here, that's the system working as intended.  I wouldn't exactly consider "reading the close banner" to be "doing a full search", but then again I also consider "doing a full search" an expectation.  That you don't is also telling, and an indication that you're going to have problems with SO's system.

Comment: @leerssej: Regarding your edit, I proposed [a similar feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186722/can-we-have-the-ability-to-flag-for-reopening) back when that was done on Meta Stack Exchange, but it got declined. The best you can do as a <3K user, is to edit the question, as that adds it to the "reopen queue" under certain circumstances. A meta post is also can work sometimes, but it can backfire, as you see...

Comment: @leerssej You won't get any argument from me that there are lots of people that don't understand how SO works.  Why do they need a button?  You just said that they wouldn't know what to do with it, so it's *better* that they don't have it.

Comment: @leerssej Any site with this much activity, and this much of *people's own unpaid time* put into it will naturally evolve "power structures"; if it didn't it would collapse into anarchy and become useless. You call for "democracy", but that's just another kind of power structure. Stack Exchange's model is more like a "meritocracy" - it tries to automatically give rights and responsibilities to those who have a track record within the community. Don't think of "you" and "us", and DEMAND THINGS IN ALL CAPS; become one of us, and work with us to make the process clearer.

Comment: The up vote or down vote button could appear on the 'Closed as Off Topic' ruling if that question continued to be voted up as useful. Does this happen already?

Comment: Popularity != on-topic-ness.  If you feel that a question is good and can be made on topic, then edit it to be so, then vote to reopen, or if you can't vote bring it up in a relevant chat room or on meta as a reopen request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any way we can democratically remove these smudges upon the collective knowledge base and reopen useful and relevant Question threads?

Yes, there is. Once you reach [3000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions), you will be able to cast reopen votes on a closed question:

> #### How do I cast a close vote on a question?
>
> ...
>
> To cast a close vote -- or just to view the current count of close votes and reasons -- click the 'close' link under the question body.
>
> ...
>
> #### What happens when a question is closed?
>
> ...
>
> Closed questions can be reopened through a similar voting process.

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no way to remove people from the community just because you don't like them or the fact that they've voted to close questions you don't want to see closed.  Of course, you can pretty easily get *yourself* removed from the community by continuing your use of personal insults at others.

As far as getting questions reopened, anyone that can vote to close questions can also vote to reopen them, if they actually feel that the question no longer merits closure.

With respect to your specific example, that's a system administration question, not a programming question, and as such is not on topic here, as the close reason stated.  There *is* an SE site where system administration questions are on topic, and that's Server Fault (or potentially Web Masters, depending on the specifics of your question).

Comment: @leerssej Yes, and as some passing user that hasn't demonstrated that they have a strong enough understanding of what does and does not belong on the site, you don't have the ability to vote to reopen questions.  For the same reason, you also don't have the ability to vote to close questions.  Are you actually proposing that anyone be able to vote to close and reopen questions, rather than just users who've used the site for long enough to have earned a bit of reputation?

Comment: @leerssej Closing a question is not deleting it.  There also isn't any incentive for people to close questions, beyond their intrinsic motivation to make the site, and the internet, a better place.  That you seem to think most closed questions shouldn't be closed appears to stem from you not understanding what questions should be closed, so again, that you aren't in a position to determine what questions are closed is *the system working as intended*.  Finally, as has been said numerous time, there *is* a button to reopen questions.

Comment: @leerssej but... if you don't know how the community works, or what is acceptable and not acceptable on this site... why should your vote for reopening count? We give this privilege to users who proved they know the platform (now.... rep is a BAD indicator for that, but that's a separate discussion). If we open reopen to everyone, we will get people to reopen stuff that has been established as off-topic (like resource requests).

Comment: @leerssej: "*In my travels I am finding that far too many appear to be improperly adjudicated and forced out of existence.*" How do you know what is "improperly adjudicated" and what is not? Furthermore, closing questions does not force anything out of existence. Please stop with the hyperbole.

Answer (score 2):

No moderators (denoted with a diamond next to their name) were involved in closing that particular question; this was done instead by five members of the community.

To that point, I'm not sure I see anything particularly *wrong* with the question; it could do with some editing but I don't see it as off-topic.  Also, the answer is pretty good; if I were still doing PHP on Windows I'd probably want that as a viable resource.

I'd personally cast a reopen vote for it after I edited the question.

Comment: I mean... this kind of question *used* to be on topic, now it isn't due to it being a server administration question, not a programming question.

Comment: @KevinB:  XAMPP (at least back when I bothered with PHP in 2005 and 2006) was commonly used for local development.  That may have changed in the ten or so years since, but I'm not bothered by this question in the least.  More importantly, the kind of answer that it received *and* the attention it's received over the years indicate to me that allowing a question like this to disappear would be pretty unfortunate.

Comment: @Makoto That would be a reason to not delete it.  It isn't, and has never been, deleted.  It's merely been closed to indicate that it's not on topic here, which it isn't.

Comment: @Servy: It is on topic. A web server is a 
["software tool commonly used by programmers"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I mean... by that definition so is a load balancer, and a router, and a computer.

Comment: @Servy:  You would have a stronger point if this weren't someone trying to configure XAMPP for their local Windows XP machine.  I wholeheartedly agree with the server configuration piece, but I'm giving the benefit of the doubt here to the OP in that they were actually configuring this sort of thing for their local development practices.  I don't disagree that it wouldn't be a surprise that someone would *try* to run a production server through their Windows XP machine, but in this scenario, in the way it reads, I don't see that as likely.

Comment: @user000001 No, it's a tool used *by system administrators*.  Administering a system is something you do when administering a system, not when programming.  That's why a whole separate site was created for system administration topics; they're not on topic on SO.

Comment: @user000001:  To put a finer point on it, there is merit to what Servy is stating; there's just a finer nuance to it from my perspective.

Comment: @Servy: Then please go burninate [htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.htaccess) x52,931.

Comment: @user000001:  [There's a finer nuance to *that*, too...](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283033/1079354)

Comment: @user000001 Just looking over the few most recent questions, most of them aren't actually server configuration questions, but rather programming questions by people that just happen to be using that platform (which isn't appropriate use of the tag, but alas, seems to make up a very large percentage of its questions given my quick skim of it).

Comment: Through sysadmins would curse at you for using any of those tools, @Servy.

Comment: @Servy: In the linked question the OP mentioned: "I just installed XAMPP on my Windows XP machine ..." etc. It seems to be more about setting up a development environment, rather than setting up a production server. Anyway, it will probably get closed again, and deleted, now that it is linked from meta.

Comment: @user000001 That statement does *not* mean that it's for a development environment.  It could just as easily, if not more easily, mean that it is simply an amature application rather than a professional application.  But anyway, like I said, the process itself is a system administration process, not a programming process, and as such isn't on topic on SO.